# I am confused on faq dialogflow project

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a project in which I have to implement 1 million FAQ on Dialogflow and upload it to the google assistant platform what will be the best way for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the FAQ files ready, I would recommend using Dialogflow ES's built-in Knowledge component. You can upload the FAQ files directly as a new knowledge base in the Knowledge tab. You can also have a bit of control over this since it allows you to disable certain questions/answers if you no longer want them to appear as a response. Dialogflow supports integration through Google Assistant (now on Google Actions for testing and deployment). I would recommend setting that up while testing the FAQ bot

Edit: if your CSV is giving an error when uploaded, try a different file or run it through a validation test. It could be that the file is corrupt. If this works on no CSV files, then it might be a bug and you should report the error to the Dialogflow platform.

Comment: I tried the same with the CSV file attached above in question and it is giving me an error check the updated question description.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement FAQ on Dialogflow, and use it in the Google Assistant Platform is to utilize the [Knowledge Connectors](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/knowledge-connectors) feature.

To do this:

1. [Enable the beta feature](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/knowledge-connectors#enable-beta-features) of your Dialogflow agent.
2. Create a [knowledge base](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/knowledge-bases) and document.

   You define one or more knowledge bases, which are collections of knowledge documents(For example, FAQ).

   To define or manage the [Knowledge Bases](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/knowledge-bases) on Dialogflow, you need to check your knowledge document file if it meets the following requirements specific to [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/knowledge-bases#supported-content):

   - CSV files must use commas as delimiters, or CSV files must have questions in the first column and answers in the second, with no header.

     **Note:** CSV documents must have exactly two columns.
   - Use CSV whenever possible, because CSV is parsed most accurately.
   - Public HTML content with a single QA pair is not supported.
   - The number of QA pairs in one document should not exceed 2000.
   - Duplicate questions with different answers are not supported.
   - You can use any FAQ document; the FAQ parser is capable of handling most FAQ formats.
   - Google Assistant responses have a 640 character limit per chat bubble, so long answers are truncated when integrating with Google Assistant.
   - The maximum document size is 50 MB.
3. [Enable Knowledge Bases](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/knowledge-connectors#settings) for your agent.
4. [Configure](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/knowledge-connectors#response-config) the responses.
5. Test in Dialogflow ES Simulator by typing one of your questions to
   see if it works successfully.
6. Integrate your agent with Google Assistant.

Comment: How many documents I can upload if one document can have a 2000 columns limit then I have around 400,000 columns right now what's the limit for document?